# Summate value of matching property in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In C#, we have a `.Sum(Predicate)` method that lets you use a lambda expression to do a summation over a collection of objects. For instance, if I had the following set of objects (using JSON for simplicity)

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Sub": {
      "Size": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Sub": {
      "Size": 3
    }
  }
]
```

And I wanted to get the sum of the sizes, I could do `Sum(n => n.Sub.Size)`

Is there a way to do something like this in javascript? I am really new (and weak) at the language and am having trouble performing a similar function. I am using jQuery, so I am open to that opening anything too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b.Sub.Size;
}, 0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sUCTK/

Documentation: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Note this is not available in some browsers (we all know which).

Comment: @jbabey: yep :-) And for them there is a shim function on the documentation page available

Comment: @Ciel: open MDN page and scroll down to Compatibility section. The implementation below the title is it. "Shim" is a common name for an implementation for old browsers that don't support required function/feature yet.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you'll need to manually step through the array and add up the values:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i in a) {
  sum += a[i].Sub.Size
}
// sum now contains the total
```

Comment: I would avoid using `in` to traverse an array. `in` is for enumeration, not iteration. If we prototyped Array with a new member, I think you'd traverse that member.

Answer (score 0):

For cross-browser compatibility, you could do this:

```
var sum = function(arr, callback, initial_value) {
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
        initial_value = 0;
    }
    var ret = initial_value;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ret += callback(arr[i]);
    }        

    return ret;    
};

console.log(sum(arr, function(element) {
    return element.Sub.Size;
});
```

This would also let you sum other summable objects, like strings, by passing the appropriate-type `initial_value`.

@zerkms shows how to use new ECMAScript standards to better sum things.

Comment: Hm... What is the use of sending a `null` as third parameter to use as initial value?

Comment: @Guffa That's how I learned to send optional parameters. In retrospect, there actually is an `arguments.length` that I've forgotten about — I'll change it.

Comment: Now it makes more sense. I think that you got the condition backwards, as it changed anything that wasn't `null` to `0`, i.e. if you sent `""` it would change it to `0`.